# Strange file permissions for cifs mounted folder

Tags: linux, file-permissions, cifs

I have a folder on my windows machine which is mounted to my linux machine using cifs. Today when accessing that folder I was denied access. When I checked file permissions I found out that it was showing very strange permissions, username, size and lastmodified date. Screenshot below:

[image]

When I checked the mounted folders using `df -h` I saw that this folder is not listed. What might be case of such a behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My be windows machine was rebooted or hibernated and mount.cifs fails to re-read or re-mount it properly.
If you still the same problem  - try to remount it and check logs in your windows machine and make sure you set correct power options in windows PC.